# jQuery Validation Email Domain "AddMethod" Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been scouring SO here to find an answer, but am coming up short...

I have this addMethod for the jquery Validator script:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailz", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@gmail.com$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid Email. ie... mrbrown@gmail.com");
```

I've added it to the:

```
$('#id').validate({
  rules: {
   emailz:{required:true},
   otherrulesworking:{},
   ect:{}
  }
})
```

Other rules are working that are part of the additional .js file. Also, emailz is a unique ID.

I get no error and the required doesn't work from the rules. Why isn't the rule working?

using jquery validation 1.11.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <strike>You need to put all of your rules ***inside*** of the `rules` option.</strike> *edit: OP updated*
- You need to assign the rule to a field *only* by the field's `name` attribute.
- You seem to be assigning the `required` rule to the `emailz` method/rule.  You cannot assign a rule to a rule.   Your `emailz` rule can only be declared by a boolean `true`.

```
$('#myform').validate({      // <- initialize the plugin on form with id="myform"
    rules: {                 // <- option
        somefield: {         // <- field name
            emailz: true,    // <- a rule/method declared
            required: true   // <- another rule/method declared 
        },
        anotherfield: {
            required: true
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ah! I see... I was using it wrong. Let me give that  shot.

Comment: Yes, worked... was using it incorrectly. I have you now email rule! Thanks a bunch :)